# how to hide global variable of Amplitude

Tags: javascript, amplitude-analytics

Does anyone use [Amplitude](https://amplitude.zendesk.com/hc/en-us)?

I just integrate this analysis tool in my side project.

I follow the [resource](https://github.com/amplitude/Amplitude-Javascript) of how to setup,

but later, I found out that I could access variable `Amplitude` and do `logEvent` in my console.log on my website.

It would not be ok if others can do the same thing and will pollute my analysis

data with no doubt

Any idea to hide a global variable which is loaded async ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can only "hide" variables using function scope, but then your variable wouldn't be global...

Comment: yes, I know that way. I just want to know is there anything I miss in Amplitude tutorial

Comment: as a third party client js library, there is no way to avoid your users/clients open the console and use Amplitude vars. Same happens with Google Analytics, you can open console of any other website and track something

Answer (score 0):

As someone from working @Amplitude I can say we haven't really seen any attempts to pollute analytics by sending events from the client side. Any data pollution issues I've seen tend to be customers code related.

There isn't any really effective way to stop this I can think of and as mentioned above other tracking tools have the same issue.

That if you are a free tier user you can block events/properties in ingestion https://amplitude.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/235649848-Settings within Amplitude

If you are paid user with Taxonomy you can do more advanced rule-based sanitation & alerts  https://amplitude.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001477311-Taxonomy

Or you set automatic monitoring messages to fire based on a set confidence interval of specific event volume or incorrect event content if you have insights. https://amplitude.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001764612#alert-conditions